# Angular - stateParams in route resolve?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Getting my head around route resolves and wondering is it ok to use $stateParams in the following manner.

```
 .state('movie', {
            url:'/movie/:id',
            templateUrl: 'partials/movie.html', 
            controller: 'MovieController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                movie: function(movieService){
                    return movieService.getMovie($stateParams.id);
                }
            }
        });
```

considering the URL won't change until the route is resolved, will the id param still be passed into the function?

Since the id is pulled from the stateParams and the state won't change until the route is resolved, does this mean using it in this fashion won't work?

Thanks and merry Christmas :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It will work, but just tweak your code a bit like this:

```
.state('movie', {
        url:'/movie/:id',
        templateUrl: 'partials/movie.html', 
        controller: 'MovieController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
            movie: function(movieService, $stateParams){
                return movieService.getMovie($stateParams.id);
            }
        }
    });
```

Notice the "$stateParams" as an argument in the resolve method.